# What is the chord of the second bar of KV310/1

Tags: chords, keyboard, analysis, mozart, sonata

The score of the beginning first movement of Mozart's KV310 sonate can be seen and heard [here](http://www.pianolibrary.org/composers/mozart/sonata-310/#1).

The first bar is the chord **a minor**, but what about the second bar (mi sol# si re la)?

Comment: The a is not part of the chord, but a pedal point; can you answer your own question now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E7/A.   As @11684 commented, a tonic pedal.  A common device in Classical music, where the architecture depends very much on firmly establishing the tonic tonality before contrasting with it.

Dominant pedals are also common.

Comment: Interesting. I suppose it's a tonic pedal because the pedal note is A. - Could one also take an other note for a (non tonic) pedal? - Was the tonic pedal used because the A is already present as lowest note in the first bar?

Comment: You can indeed. The dominant, for instance.